# Is there a Linux standard structure for "install" directories?

Tags: linux, software-distribution, fhs

I want to release a small software package, but I'm not sure how to structure the release directory.

*Is there a Linux standard out there that specifies how to name of each directory in my release folder and what to put in them (or not put)?*

For example, I expect compiled libraries to be in `/lib` and header files in `/include` - etc.  I have a few other files in the release and it's not clear to me in what directory to put them.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a Linux standard out there that specifies how to name of each directory ?

More or less, read about the [File Hierarchy Standard](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/lsb/fhs) (see also [this](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/) and the [FHS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) & [LSB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Standard_Base) wikipages). See also [hier(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/hier.7.html) man page.

But it describes *system-wide* paths. Notice that libraries often go into `/usr/lib/` (or `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` ...) and header files into `/usr/include/`. For software outside of and unknown by your [package manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_manager), you'll use `/usr/local/lib/` for libraries and `/usr/local/include/` for headers. Be also aware of [pkg-config](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/pkg-config/).

BTW, you should consider making these directories configurable (at least at build time).

Read also about [autoconf](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/index.html) and the `--prefix` argument (default is `/usr/local/`) to its `configure` scripts.

Also, consider packaging your software (e.g. as [`.deb` packages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deb_(file_format)) on Ubuntu or Debian). This also means to describe dependencies. 
See also [GNU stow](https://www.gnu.org/software/stow/).

If your software package is some [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) (I hope it is, then publish its source code, perhaps on [github](http://github.com/)) you might get help from distribution packagers. And you should look into how similar free software are dealing with that.